# p,q are two propositions.It is given that, p ⇒ q is true.Consider the following conclusions,

Tags: propositional-calculus

1. $ \neg p\rightarrow\neg q$ is true
2. $\neg q\rightarrow\neg p$ is true
3. $p\rightarrow  \neg p∨q$ is true

Now which one is the correct? and explain this.Thanks!

Comment: Make  a four-row truth table and check!

Comment: @ncmathsadist I'm sorry, but that's really not necessary. There's a quicker way to do this.

Comment: Note that $p\Rightarrow q$ is logically equivalent to $\neg p \vee q$

Comment: True, but making the tables is very simple and the OP should have thought of that as a fail-safe.

Comment: @ncmathsadist If you can please make a table and mention it here.It will be useful for viewers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NOTE: $\sim p$ means "not p", $\sim q$ means "not q".

1. $\sim p \implies \sim q$ is called the inverse of a conditional statement. The inverse is not always true given the original.

For example, if $p$ is false and $q$ is true, then we know the original is true because it has a false hypothesis, but the inverse is false because it has a true hypothesis, but a false conclusion.

Therefore, we can not conclude this.

2. $\sim q \implies \sim p$ is called the contrapositive of a conditional statement. The contrapositive is always true given the original, so we can conlude that this is true.
3. $p \implies (\sim p \vee q)$ is something I've never seen before, but it means we have to assume $p$ and then prove $\sim p \vee q$.

Thus, let's assume $p$.

> We know that $p \implies q$, so with $p$, we can conclude $q$.
>
> Now, since we have $q$, we also have $v \vee q$, where $v$ can be absolutely anything, since anything in a conjunction with a true statement is true.
>
> Therefore, we can make $v=\sim p$ to conclude that $\sim p \vee q$.

Thus, we have successfully proven $\sim p \vee q$ given $p$, so we can conclude $p \implies (\sim p \vee q)$.

If you want to check my reasoning, you can do what [@ncmathsadist](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/4154/ncmathsadist) did and make a truth table for all of these statements.

Comment: Interesting. I agree with you that the 3 statements should be fairly obvious without a truth table. So the quickest way to an answer is not the truth table. But this answer was more laborious to prepare than truth tables! Still, it is more informative! +!

Comment: @NobleMushtak First of all Thanx for the answer & I'm sorry for out of this.Is there any good Ebook or Web Site to refer about "Predicate and Quantifiers".Thnx Again...

Comment: @lijaro I don't know if this is what you want, but personally, I learned [a lot about logic from this Web site](http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/secondary/index.html).

Comment: @NobleMushtak Thanx Again :)